# Choose one of three outcomes based on chance

Tags: c

I'm new to C/C++. I want to write a program that 25% of the time prints "horse", 50% of the time prints "dog" and 25% of the time prints "cat".

I have the following code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    if ((rand() % 100) < 25) {
        printf("horse\n");
    }
    if ((rand() % 100) < 50) {
        printf("dog\n");
    }
    if ((rand() % 100) < 25) {
        printf("cat\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that it prints sometimes prints several things, and sometimes it prints nothing. I want only one thing printed each run.

Comment: Simple way: Use a counter, and fall back to other cases if counter fills up. :)

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++? They are different languages and the answer will be different.

Comment: Consider using else-if

Comment: What is UB mean? I want to learn C and C++. How will be different?

Comment: To put it simple: Just because both start with the same letter does not mean they are the saem language or C is a subset of C++. They are **different** languages! So, first concentrate on **one** then you might learn the other. But do not mix them!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int percent = rand() % 100;

    if (percent < 25) {
        printf("horse\n");
    } else if (percent < 75) {
        printf("dog\n");
    } else {
        printf("cat\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem with your code is that you are "rolling" for each outcome. That makes all the outcomes independent of each other. What I've done above is roll the random number once. Then we look at the cumulative probability for each outcome. This insures exactly one outcome will run. Also notice the use of `else if`.

Comment: No, `%100` is correct. This gives 100 outcomes, 0 through 99 inclusive. The first condition checks for 25 possible outcomes, 0 through 24. The second conditional checks for 50 outcomes, 25 through 74. The last else gets the remaining 25 outcomes, 75 through 99.

Comment: @FiddlingBits no, the probabilities are exactly as they are intended to be this way. 0-24 Horse (25 values), 25-74 Dog (50 values), 75-99 cat (25 values). One thing is, that it isn't _perfectly_ equally distributed, but this shouldn't be noticable in praxis.

Comment: That does not provide evenly distributed results, even iff `rand` does. And the `srand(...)` for every call will also inhibit proper random values if the proram is called within short time-intervals. OPs approach will not work with  the standard random functions.

Comment: @Olaf how so? Do you mean that `RANDMAX` is probably not evenly divisible by 100? I was just adapting joe's code, fixing his bug, but keeping the same method.

Comment: The first half, yes. But the problem is much broader. Just think what you get when running that program too fast for the time to change.